# What happens to the distribution of the induced angle of attack, if we suppose the circulation distribution is constant?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, lift

Assuming the lifting-line theory, we know the circulation must go to zero at the tips of the wing. Therefore, I wonder if we can actually conceive such an idea as a constant circulation across the whole wing span, and if yes, would the induced angle be zero for all of the points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you postulate is only possible with a wing of infinite span. Here, circulation is indeed constant over span because the wing has no end, and the induced angle of attack is zero.

Once the wing is **not** infinite, the wingtip forces circulation to zero, as you say. Since induction in subsonic flow reaches infinitely in all directions, this jump in circulation will not be confined to the wingtip but will influence the amount of circulation over the whole wing, so the decrease in circulation strength will happen gradually over span.

If that distribution happens to be elliptical, with the wingspan being one half axis of the ellipse, the induced angle of attack is constant over span. If you now twist the wing locally to bend the circulation distribution into a more rectangular shape, the induced angle of attack will become smaller at mid-wing but larger towards the tips. But no amount of twisting will make the circulation distribution completely rectangular.